# PHP i have no idea why this math query doesnt work

Tags: php

```
echo "<a href=/browsepage.php?category=$category&pagenumber=($i +1)>($i +1)</a>";
```

why does the output show (0+1) instead of 1 and the url truncates at $category.

A second set of eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because you're  quoting it to make it a string literal, so `$i` will be interpolated because you're using double quotes, but the rest (the brackets, the plus sign, the `1`) are just part of the string.... `echo $i +1;` without the quotes will evaluate the expression before echoing the result

Comment: thanks mark. i need to study more because i didnt undderstand how to fix it from your comments although after reading through it and seeing the examples i understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `$i + 1` expression outside the quotes:

```
echo "<a href='/browsepage.php?category=$category&pagenumber=".($i + 1)."'>".($i + 1)."</a>";
```

(because mathematical expressions inside quotes are not being evaluated, they are simply taken as a text)

Comment: You're missing any kind of explanation (particularly as this is a _why_ question).

Comment: thanks guys! i coldnt get it with the first comment but with the examples shown above i understand now.

Answer (score -1):

First, you have som typos in your code. Second, some concatenating issues are involved. Try this one instead:

```
echo '<a href="/browsepage.php?category='.$category.'&pagenumber='. ($i+1) .'">'. ($i+1) .'</a>';
```

The "outcome show (0+1) instead of 1" because the expression can not be evaluated by PHP before echoing the result.

Comment: thanks! both your examples were clear. i understand now!